# Access _users table in SocialEngine?

Tags: zend-framework, socialengine

i got a (simple?) problem accessing _users table in SocialEngine. To access tables in SE4 i use this:

```
$table = Engine_Api::_()->getDbTable(tablename,tablegroup);
```

and this works fine for _user_online (*->getDbTable('online','user')*) etc. but I don't know how to access _users table (which has not tablegroup prefix).

i tried:

- ->getDbTable('users')
- ->getDbTable('','users')
- ->getDbTable(null,'users')
- ->getDbTable('foo','what_a')

no way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Engine_Api::_()->getItemTable('user');`

I suggest you read SocialEngine factory codes to find out answer to this kind of questions.

Comment: yup! yeah you're right man but sometimes is messy without a codex! where should i've found this?

Comment: Like I said, read factory codes and see how they retrieve data from users table.

Comment: Try to find the definition of the function `getItemTable`. You can use a folder search or something. Once you read some code you will know which class to look into.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing commas

try this

$table = Engine_Api::_()->getDbTable('users','user');

it will give you users table object. hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

You can use below 2 methods to get the "engine4_users" table object:

1) $userTable = Engine_Api::_()->getItemTable('user);

2) $userTable = Engine_Api::_()->getDbTable('users', 'user');

Comment: What is the difference between these two methods?

Comment: There is no difference in terms of output, both will return the same object of the User_Model_DbTable_Users class. There is one difference is that getItemTable is called using the item defined at "application/modules/User/manifest.php" and getDbTable is using the table names. For more details you can check the getItemTable method at file path: "application/libraries/Engine/Api.php" and getDbTable method at file path: "application/libraries/Engine/ServiceLocator/Backend/DbTable.php".

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
$query=Engine_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter()->select()
              ->from('engine4_yourtablename')
              ->where("your_field_name = ?", $variable)->limit(1);

              $query= $query->query()->fetch();
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: this is not the best idea as it results in another SQL query at that point in the code. By using the API, Zend will intelligently group the queries together, resulting in fewer database calls.